# How to set print setup properties on Existing Document with Apache PDFBox

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am new to apache PDFBox api and I want to set print setup properties with apache PDFBox.

Here I want to set the page size to `A4` and I also want to set Print Scaling option to `NO SCALING`.

Make a note here that I have a ready PDF input stream which I am loading. So I want to set there print properties with `org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument` class before printing.

How can I do that ?

**EDITED :**

Here is my class to print the PDF file. Note that **TODO**  marker where I want to add code the change PDF page size to **A4** and to set page scaling to **NO SCALING**.

```
public class PrintPDF extends Applet{
    private PrintPDF(){
        //static class
    }


    public static void main(String a[]) throws Exception{
        System.out.println("Printing Started...");
        String password = "";
        String pdfFile = "D://TEST//output.pdf";
        boolean silentPrint = true;
        String printerindx = "1";

        PrintService defaultService = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();            


        if( pdfFile == null )
        {
            usage();
        }

        PDDocument document = null;
        try
        {
            document = PDDocument.load( pdfFile );

            //TODO : ADD CODE TO SET PAPER SIZE TO A4 AND 
            //ADD CODE TO SET PAGE SCALING TO : NO SCALING

            if( document.isEncrypted() )
            {
                document.decrypt( password );
            }
            PrinterJob printJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();

            if(printerindx != null )
            {
                PrintService[] printServices = PrinterJob.lookupPrintServices();

                for(PrintService printService : printServices){
                    if(printService.getName().equals("FG_LASER_PRINTER")){
                        printJob.setPrintService(printService);
                    }
                }
                            }

            if( silentPrint ){
                document.silentPrint( printJob );
            }else{
                document.print( printJob );
            }
        }
        finally{
            if( document != null ){
                document.close();
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Printing Completed...");
    }

    /**
     * This will print the usage requirements and exit.
     */
    private static void usage()
    {
        System.err.println( "Usage: java org.apache.pdfbox.PrintPDF [OPTIONS] <PDF file>\n" +
                "  -password  <password>        Password to decrypt document\n" +
                "  -silentPrint                 Print without prompting for printer info\n"
        );
        System.exit( 1 );
    }
}
```

Comment: Please put your code here so it would be easier to visualize your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should able to do this by by updating the Paper of your PageFormat.

```
pdDocument.getPageFormat().getPaper().setSize(double width, double length);
```

the width and length are in inch. A4 size is 8.27 × 11.69 inch.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Rudy. Let me give this a try and will let you know if its working or not. Also tell me, can we change the print scaling option ??

Comment: For me it did print a small A7 excerpt of my document again

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and I felt like it was way too difficult to do this one simple thing. For me, the accepted answer pdDocument.getPageFormat(int page) is deprecated and unusable. Even though it's not ideal, I eventually settled for the following - not even using the PDFBox printing.

The following code converts the pages to images one at a time and uses java2d to resize and print them out.

```
PDDocument pdfdoc = PDDocument.load(pdfPane.pdfFile);
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
final List<PDPage> pdfPages = pdfdoc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();

PrinterJob pjob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
pjob.setJobName(pdfPane.pdfFile.getName());
pjob.setPrintable(new Printable()
{
  @Override
  public int print( Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int page ) throws PrinterException
  {
    if (page > pdfPages.size())
      return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
    try
    {
      g.drawImage(pdfPages.get(page).convertToImage()
                ,(int)pf.getImageableX()
                ,(int)pf.getImageableY()
                ,(int)pf.getImageableWidth()
                ,(int)pf.getImageableHeight()
                ,null);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
      LoggerUtil.error(e);
    }
    return PAGE_EXISTS;
  }
});
pjob.print();
pdfdoc.close();
```